# How much pressure can human withstand if inner and outer pressure is balanced?

Tags: human-biology, respiration, extremophiles

I know human can't dive too deep because there's pressure difference between inside and outside of the body. But how much pressure can human withstand if human is breathing components that is surrounding him?

So I have two questions: 
1.How much pressure can human handle if he is surrounded by regular air (also breathing air)? 2. How much pressure can human handle if he is floating in oxygen-rich liquid and breathing it at the same time ([Liquid Breathing](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/into-the-abyss-the-diving-suit-that-turns-men-into-fish-2139167.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_breathing))?

There's a similar question, but it doesn't have answer that fully satisfies me. [Highest Pressure Human Body Can Survive In?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/highest-pressure-human-body-can-survive-in)

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange. The physiological responses to breathing 'regular air' under pressure are very well understood (a good answer could be based on medical studies of regular SCUBA divers), whereas the liquid breathing techniques are extremely experimental and under-studied, so any answer would have to be very hypothetical. I suggest splitting these off into two separate questions, because the answers will be basically unrelated.

Comment: Most issues with typical diving technology involve compression/dissolution/ or expansion of gas. But for extreme depths, if you assume you can eliminate issues related to gases, there is virtually no limit as long as the rate of compression allows (fluid) equalization of pressure through the cell walls. Too rapid compression/expansion can result in similar affects as exposure to hypotonic/hypertonic solutions - crenation or rupturing effects. The bulk elastance of water - very 'stiff'